# Cannot print out retrieved Array List object

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, firebase

I cannot print out my array list object.

Here is my first class to return the arraylist object:

```
public class user_arraylist {
public ArrayList<String> get_user_det()    {
    final ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(); //declare arraylist
    
    Firebase f_user = new Firebase("https://shareurdaydb.firebaseio.com/User/");
    f_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap_user) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> rs = snap_user.getChildren();
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> irs = rs.iterator();
            long allNum2 = snap_user.getChildrenCount();
            int maxNum2 = (int)allNum2;
            int count_user = 1;
            while(irs.hasNext())
            {
                if(count_user <= maxNum2)
                {
                    Firebase user_data = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"); 
                    AuthData authData = user_data.getAuth();
                    Map<String, Object> nPost = (Map<String, Object>) irs.next().getValue();
                    
                    String db_email = nPost.get("email_addr").toString();
                    //String reply_msg_id = nPost.get("msgid").toString();

                    if (authData != null) {
                        String usr_email = authData.getProviderData().get("email").toString();
                        if(usr_email.equals(db_email))
                        {
                            String disp_name = nPost.get("disp_name").toString();
                            String real_name = nPost.get("real_name").toString();
                            temp.add(disp_name); //add to arraylist
                            temp.add(real_name);
                            
                            for (String str : temp) {
                                            System.out.println("Item is: " + str); //working 
                                        }

                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Failed");
                    }
                }
                count_user++;
            }                       
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
}); 
return(temp); //return array list

 }
```

}

> Item is: John
>
> Item is: Joe

but it does not work when I retrieve to another class.

Here is my second class to retrieve the array list object and display it:

```
                    user_arraylist t = new user_arraylist();
                    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                    arr = t.get_user_det(); //not sure if this is how you retrieve.
                    
                    //Object user_det = get_user_det();
                    for (String temp : arr) {
                        System.out.println("NAME + " + temp); //does not work
                    }
```

After running this it prints out: nothing

If I print it like this

> System.out.println("NAME + " + arr.toString());

It gives me NAME:[];

Can some one explain why it is not working (in the second class it's not printing out the array list)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? What does this code do instead?

Comment: cannot print out the array list in second class

Comment: What happens instead? What is the size of the ArrayList?

Comment: I added in the comments for clearer. What happens is "it prints out"     >NAME:[]

Comment: have you verified that your arraylist in not empty ?

Comment: Well I have check when I add in the array it  works as shown in first class but when I return the object to second class it could become empty or maybe my code is wrong..

Comment: It might be that the segment of code shown to us located in your 2nd class never occurs for one reason or another. Try to print something before the segment shown.

Comment: I got this working using another way.

Answer (score -1):

Do this but this will work when your user_list returns data

```
user_arraylist t = new user_arraylist();
                    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<t.size();i++){
                   arr.add(t.get(i))
}

                    //Object user_det = get_user_det();
                    for (String temp : arr) {
                        System.out.println("NAME + " + temp); //does not work
                    }
```

Comment: Dude this is the way to add and item to the array list, instead of making giving negative vote learn some basic of java first.

Comment: I didnt make the negative vote and besides you have no concepts or explanation of any sort.

Comment: You cant use add after you gotten the object it does not make any sense.